# Regex to replace email addresses

Tags: c#, regex

I wish to replace email addresses in a string to something else.  It does not work for me.

```
    string body = "this is a test abc@emailadx.com";  
    string pattern = @"\b[!#$%&'*+./0-9=?_`a-z{|}~^-]+@[.0-9a-z-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}\b";

    Regex.Replace(body, pattern, "Hidden Email Address");
    return body;
```

Any hints would be helpful please.

Comment: Your used language would be useful, too. Thats what the tags are for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
return Regex.Replace(body, pattern, "Hidden Email Address");
```

If you look at the documentation for [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx), you'll see that it *returns* the newly replaced string.  It does not affect the string that was passed in.

**NOTE**: this is assuming you're using C#.  But I'm guessing you are, from the syntax.

**FURTHERMORE**: If your regex still isn't working well, try this one from the Regular Expressions Cookbook (by Goyvaerts & Levithan):

```
@"^[\w!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^.-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+$"
```

Comment: I see that your pattern looks like the most restrictive one from the cookbook...that one is good for validation, but if you just want to replace emails, you might want a more relaxed regex like the one above ("Simple, with all characters" in the book)